# How to add sql queries in Itemreader class

Tags: spring-batch

I want to use sql static queries in my reader class. But queries are quite big hence not adding to xml file. Then how to write multiple queries in reader class ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

quick and dirty; just extend JdbcCursorItemReader and set the sql from there:

```
public class StaticSqlJdbcCursorItemReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader {
    //extend your reader
  public static final STATIC_SQL = "select * from ..." 

  public StaticSqlJdbcCursorItemReader() {
        setSql(STATIC_SQL);
    }

}
```